# How to make a dynamic page Item in Flutter?

Tags: listview, flutter

I use a pageView which includes `listView`
In each `listView` I make a bottom to dynamic add a container with a `DropdownButton`,

My goal is to make a dynamic page with the dynamic `listView` and each page is independent.

Thanks, hope you guys have a good day

Answer (score 0):

You can use an Stack wideget to use them independently, and create each widget individually, for the listView and the pageView, you should use the listView.Builder and the pageView.Builder to have a dynamic Widget , take  look in the flutter documentation about how to use